# Android open source project for video encoding and decoding?

Tags: android, video, benchmarking

I am trying to run a benchmark using Android open source application. I am looking for an open source application that I can test video encoding and video decoding.

I tried with vidiom but it used MediaRecorder from Android sdk so I couldn't able to actually see and measure the performance.

Do you guys know any other Android open source application so I can run some video encoding and decoding test on Android device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any open source video convert application?